# Windows Authentication with Identity Server 4 and ASP.NET Core and Angular8 SPA

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, identityserver3

I've been reading articles and StackOverflow topics for few days but I have not found answer.

Could anyone familiar with IS4 tell me if this scenario may be achieved?

I would like to build a SPA application (written in Angular 8) and configure it to login via IS4 with full SSO. User can see few redirects related to IS4 nature, but should not be forced to click anything. If for some reason SSO would not be successful user should be redirected to page where he would be asked for AD credentials or he would login using non active directory account.

Since Stackoverflow isn't website that offers free complex solutions I do not expect that. I just asking for some code samples, links, opinion.

Thanks